Exposing angular module as web component
I've been trying to expose some functionality of my app to third parties. I think it should be possible to achieve that. Here's what I've done:
Created another project in the same workspace, in there I've created a module:
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NewModule
  ],
  imports: [
    OtherProjectModule
  ],
  providers: [
  ]
})
export class NewModule{
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
  }

  ngDoBootstrap() {
    const element = createCustomElement(MyWidgetComponent, {injector: this.injector});
    customElements.define('my-widget', element);
  }
}

Then I created an index file that has only the customElement created tag
<my-widget></my-widget>

And finally, the MyWidgetComponent template only has the other module component's tag
<other-project-component></other-project-component>

When I serve the application, I run into a problem of NullInjection errors, such as these:
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError[A-> A-> B-> C-> C-> C]

So how I tried to solve it is just by adding everything from the error to the providers array of NewModule:
providers: [A, B, C]

I thought I can just brute force it by keep adding the missing dependencies to providers, but I ran into Error: NG0204, which is circular dependency (I think).
Now here are my questions:

Is the whole process what I'm doing even correct? Will I be able to
expose the module from the main application as a web component for
the third parties to use?
Is there a way for me not to specify all the providers without
changing the other project's code too much?

Thanks!

try @Optional which suppresses the DI errors, the most important question you need to check is is my component fully independent of the main module, because web component logic must be fully independent (or standalone), plus if you depended on the source module, why should it even be a web component, the module can be imported and the component can be used as is!

Okay, didn't know about the requirement of it to be fully independent. As a workaround I decided to try to build my whole main project as a library, but having troubles there. Do you think the approach I chose can produce the result I'm after?
